# O banco de dados .mdf gerado automaticamente no App_Data pode ser usado em produção?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api, code-first

A base de dados gerada automaticamente dentro da pasta App_Data em projetos `Asp.Net MVC` e `Web-Api` pode ser usada em produção ou é uma base apenas para teste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema de se usar este banco de dados é que o AttachDBFilename é uma propriedade exclusiva do SQL Server Express, ela funciona apenas como uma instancia do usuário e não pode ser usada pela rede.

Se você tem o controle sobre o SQL Server de produção é possível que você pegue os arquivos mdf e ldf para anexar eles no seu servidor do SQL Server, porém se usa uma hospedagem compartilhada isso geralmente não é uma opção, neste caso vai ser mais fácil você gerar um script para criar as tabelas mesmo.

Comment: Eu diria que principalmente no Azure ele não deve funcionar. Veja que este modo de usar o banco de dados é feito para facilitar a vida do programador durante o desenvolvimento, em produção o ambiente pode ser diferente, no caso do Azure acredito que você deveria usar o SQL Azure, mas não tenho experiencia com ele para indicar melhor.